# Change gfortran version on ubuntu

Tags: gcc

I want to change gfortran version on ubuntu 20.04. The current version of gfortran on my system is 9.3.0 but I want to switch it to 7.5 please suggest me how to do it

Answer (score 1):

To install it, run the command `sudo apt install gfortran-7` in a terminal.

Then use the command `gfortran-7` to call it during compilation.

To make it default, run the following commands

**Add it to alternatives**

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gfortran gfortran /usr/bin/gfortran-7 100
```

**Now set it as default**

```
sudo update-alternatives --set gfortran /usr/bin/gfortran-7
```